# Where In clause getting error #1224 Operand should only contain 1 column

Tags: mysql

The query below is correct with regard to the column names and table names.  A customer can have two active methods for contacting them (phone number and email).  The phone number and email address are in a child table to the parent table customer. I am clearly missing something with regard to how to use the IN clause.  Can someone help me?

```
  SELECT
DISTINCT cm.comm_method, cm.customer_id
    FROM contact_method cm
   WHERE cm.is_active = 'Y' 
     AND cm.customer_id IN 
        (SELECT oc.customer_id, c.name
           FROM customer c
     INNER JOIN org_customer oc ON c.customer_id = oc.customer_id
          WHERE oc.org_id = $org_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` clause works like this `WHERE X in (X, Y, Z)`.  Where `X, Y, Z` is a list of things to look `IN`.  What you have is `WHERE customer_name in ( (customer_id_1, customer_name_1), (customer_id_2, customer_name_2)`.

The issue is that you are including the customer names in the list of things to look `IN`.  The error message is telling you that the list of things to look `IN` must have only 1 column, so just take out c.name from the `SELECT` of your subquery.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I knew I was missing something simple.